# Cordova - callback when user creates screenshot

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I want my app to be triggered when a user creates a screenshot with the native functionality (in Android this is 'Shutdown menu' -> 'Take screenshot', on iPhone it is unlock button+home button if I am correct).

Can I add a callback function to this, so I can catch whenever a user takes a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, see http://www.raywenderlich.com/48001/easily-overlooked-new-features-ios-7#screenshot. I'm not sure what you'd need to do for Android (if it is even possible).

As to implementation, you'd need to write a custom plugin to handle it, as I'm not aware of any that currently exist.